# How to populate a text box from a listbox?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I have a listbox with combined Employee Number and Name. so what you see is 0001-John Doe but now when I try and populate a text box with the list box info it does not work.

How I populate my listbox:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
 Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
 Dim rsst As New ADODB.Recordset

   dbPath = Sheets("Info").Range("a2").Value
    conn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & dbPath      

  rsst.Open "SELECT EmpNumber,EmpFirstName,EmpSurname FROM Employees;", _
   conn, adOpenStatic

 With rsst
 .MoveFirst
  Do Until .EOF

Me.lbxNextOfKinEmployeeNumber.AddItem rsst.Fields(0).Value & " - " & rsst.Fields(1) & " " & " " & rsst.Fields(2) & " "
 rsst.MoveNext
  Loop
 End With
End Sub
```

What's in my view button:

```
Private Sub btnNextOfKinSelect_Click()
            Dim CNOK As New ADODB.Connection
            Dim RNOK As New ADODB.Recordset

            txtNextofKinEmployeeNumber.Enabled = False
            'btnEditNextOfKin.Visible = True

        If lbxNextOfKinEmployeeNumber.ListIndex = -1 Then
                MsgBox "Please Select a Employee Number"
            Else

            dbPath = Sheets("Info").Range("a2").Value
             CNOK.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & dbPath

    RNOK.Open "SELECT * FROM EmployeeNextOfKin Where EmpNumber ='" & 
     Me.lbxNextOfKinEmployeeNumber & "'", _
      CNOK, adOpenStatic
       RNOK.MoveFirst

                txtNextofKinEmployeeNumber.Value = RNOK("EmpNumber")
                txtNextOfKinName.Value = RNOK("NextOfKinName")
                txtNextOfKinSurname.Value = RNOK("NextOfKinSurname")
                txtContactNumber.Value = RNOK("NextofKinContactNumber")
                txtContactAddressLine1.Value = RNOK("NextofKinAddress")
                txtNextofKinCity.Value = RNOK("NextofKinCity")
                txtCellNumber.Value = RNOK("NextofKinCellNumber")
    End If
End Sub
```

What I want is when I select 0001-John Doe it should get the data from my database and populate my textboxes.

Comment: If you put a breakpoint at RNOK.Movefirst and then use F8, are the values actually in the fields?

Comment: so in the Where EmpNumber ='" & Me.lbxNextOfKinEmployeeNumber & "'

Comment: it does return a value the whole 0001- john doe

Comment: but breaks on the RNOK.movefirst

Comment: You don't need that line, when you open a recordset you are always on the first record, unless it's empty

Comment: ok so now it breaks on the next line and says. could nit set the value property.Property mismatch. What I think is now that I am sending the multi values from the list box. thats why its a mismatch. but i have no idea how to fix it .

Comment: Is empNumber a value or text? What does the field actually contain? If you hover your mouse over RNOK("EmpNumber") in break mode it should show you what it's set to.

Comment: txtEmployeeNumber.Value = RNOK("EmpNumber") . txtEmployeeNumber.Value="" and then RNOK("EmpNumber") shows nothing

Comment: Try adding `lbxNextOfKinEmployeeNumber.RowSourceType="Value List"` before adding the first item. When populating comboboxes/listboxes, first you need to specify what kind of source you are going to use (a list of values or a query). https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.listbox.additem Line *The RowSourceType property of the specified control must be set to Value List.*

Comment: Why using Excel pulling data from Access? Is EmpNumber actually a text field with values like `0001`?

Answer (score 0):

Code is trying to match concatenated string `0001-john doe` with EmpNumber field value `0001`. Options:

1. set listbox RowSource as multi-column

```
Do Until rsst.EOF
With Me.lbxNextOfKinEmployeeNumber
    .ColumnCount = 2
    .ColumnWidths = "0;2"
    .AddItem rsst(0) & ";" & rsst(0) & " - " & rsst(1) & " " & rsst(2)
End With
rsst.MoveNext
Loop
```

If users would prefer to type name, don't include EmpNumber in concatenated string. Last name first might be more appropriate: 
`.AddItem rsst(0) & ";" & rsst(2) & ", " & rsst(1)`
Might want to sort recordset: `ORDER BY EmpSurname`

2. extract EmpNumber from concatenated string
   `Left(Me.lbxNextOfKinEmployeeNumber, 4)`
3. use LIKE and wildcard
   `WHERE '" & Me.lbxNextOfKinEmployeeNumber & "' LIKE [EmpNumber] & '*'"`